# Use sed or awk to join lines in a certain pattern?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Not sure on how to turn this input:

```
A
B
C
apartner
bpartner
cpartner
```

into this output:

```
A apartner
B bpartner
c cpartner
```

I have this pattern in a 80 line file that needs to be 40 line. Also, how can I enclose each item, in lets say, `<il><b>A</b> <i>apartner</i></il>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `pr` from `coreutils`:

```
pr -2 -t -l 40 -s' ' $oldfile > $newfile
```

Add tags using the same `pr` and `sed`:

```
pr -2 -t -l 40 -J -S'</b> <i>' $oldfile | sed 's|^|<il><b>|;s|$|</i></il>|' > $newfile
```

output:

```
<il><b>A</b> <i>apartner</i></il>
<il><b>B</b> <i>bpartner</i></il>
<il><b>C</b> <i>cpartner</i></il>
```

Answer (score 5):

[GNU]

If it's not important to use `sed` or `awk` then I recommend this as the easiest solution:

First you split the file in two:

```
head -n 40 file >file1
tail -n 40 file >file2
```

Then you combine the lines:

```
paste --delimiters=" " file1 file2
```

Instead of `head` and `tail` you can use `sed` or `awk`, of course:

```
sed -n -e 1,40p combinedfile >file1
sed -n -e 41,80p combinedfile >file2
awk 'NR < 41 {print;}' combinedfile >file1
awk 'NR > 40 {print;}' combinedfile >file2
```

OK, I just realize: The pure awk solution isn't as complicated as I thought:

```
awk 'NR < 41 { lines[NR]=$0; next; }; {print lines[NR-40],$0}' combinedfile
```

Comment: you can skip creating file1 and file2: `paste <(head -40 file) <(tail -40 file )`